# how can access to the value? this is the result: Array ( [] => 2018 )

Tags: php

I am using SQL SERVER using php.

```
$sql="SELECT YEAR(getdate())";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
//result
$anio=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
echo print_r($anio);

this is the result:

Array ( [] => 2018 )
```

How can I access to the value "2018"?

Comment: `select year(getdate()) as whatever`, then result is in `$anio['whatever']`

Comment: echo $anio[0]; you can use.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca works... I will give the best answer..

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an alias  to the selected  columns and the refer to result using the alias name

```
    $sql="SELECT YEAR(getdate()) my_year";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    //result
    $anio=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo print_r($anio);
```

this  should return

```
    Array ( ['my_year'] => 2018 )
```

you could refer then as

```
    echo $anio['my_year'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "AS" in your SQL:

```
$sql="SELECT YEAR(getdate()) AS my_date";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
//result
$anio=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $anio['my_date'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`sqlsrv_fetch_array` returns an associative array with a pair `key=>value`

So, your SQL statment does not declare explicitly an field name, that's why it returns an empty key associated with a value.

To fix that simply associate the SQL function `YEAR(getdate())` to a field name.

```
$sql="SELECT YEAR(getdate()) AS myDate";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
$anio=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $anio['myDate'];
```

Also I recommend to take a look how php deals with arrays (see [php arrays](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php))

Best regads, pb